# How to install bower on openshift.redhat? "No compatible version found"

Tags: npm, installation, openshift, bower, redhat

I am testing `openshift.redhat` free plan. Until now, things were somewhat going fine with my deploy, until I tried installing `bower`. Search through the internet, some people advised on the following recipe:

```
HOME=$OPENSHIFT_DAT_DIR  # as you cannot write to the home folder
npm install bower
```

With the following, I get a

```
No compatible version found for abbrev;
```

So, did anyone managed to install bower with redhat openshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Command line utilities that are usually installed using the -g or --global flag will be automatically be added to the system $PATH, as long as they are included in the dependencies or devDependencies sections of the project’s package.json file.

https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-dependency-management.html

This means that if you include bower in your package.json, you will be able to use bower like normal in your application.

```
"dependencies": {
  "bower": "^1.4.1",
}
```

I found running bower more difficult...

I managed to get bower running by adding this in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "HOME=$OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR bower install || bower install"
}
```

It works on both my local machine AND Openshift.

Hope this helps